# Ho to create Facebook dev/test account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to create a Facebook account for testing Facebook GraphAPI. I am able to create a TEST account under the parent account, but due to unusual activities, my parent account gets deactivated. How can I create a Facebook account for development/testing purpose?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/

That is the only allowed way. You are only allowed to have one Facebook account and you are not allowed to share it:

https://www.facebook.com/terms.php (3.1)